# Aplicacion java esta muy lenta al conectarse con servidor en red local a base de datos mysql con xampp

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, servidor, red

Tengo una aplicacion en java la cual se conecta a una base de datos mySQL xampp, probe la conexion en mi equipo y funciona excelente, responde rapido pero la agregue a una red local para conectarse a un servidor, y al intentar hacer una consulta desde cualquier equipo de la red va demasiado lenta se demora varios segundos en cargar las consultas,alguien me puede indicar que puedo hacer para mejorar la velocidad de la aplicacion al conectarse con la BD puesto que en el servidor donde tengo instalado xampp funciona muy bien

Gracias.

Comment: Dale una redbull

Comment: A ver, no es correcto decir *una base de datos mysql xampp*, mysql es un motor de base de datos en sí mismo, y xampp es una interfaz que te permite conectar a ese motor de base de datos, como lo es phpmyadmin, workbench, u otros. ¿Por qué metes a xampp en esto? ¿Acaso desde Java intentas pasar por xampp para conectarte a la base de datos? Explica el modo en que intentas tu conexión y si es posible muestra el código. Desde Java tendrías que usar JDBC cambiando ligeramente la cadena de conexión, poniendo quizá la IP de la máquina donde está la BD.